# Laravel: AJAX Query on front-end loses data after 1 JSON variable crosses the 50,000 - 68,000 characters long

Tags: php, json, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

We currently have a function POST'ing data to our Laravel backend. On occasion, the entire request just fails with print statements on the backend revealing that the request variables are set to null.

We have diagnosed the issue to be based on the size of the query. One of the variables - a JSON string - can grow very long, and once it crosses somewhere in the 50,000 - 68,000 character range, the whole query fails.

I am stumped, however, where to look. Backend is Laravel 5.2, running on Nginx, PHP 7.2. Frontend is using AJAX called within a Vue.JS function. I assume the issue is on the backend side. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? If the query (I'm assuming this is a SQL query) is getting too much data, surely the solution is to rewrite that function so handling that much data isn't needed? If that's not the right approach and you need to embiggen the size max size of a query, we'll need to know what database you're using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: Did you get any errors? Maybe on nginx or Laravel? Any error message will lead us to know what exactly to fix.

Comment: $table->longText('description').....LONGTEXT =  4,294,967,295 bytes = ~4GB

Answer (score 1):

Here's a random stab in the dark based on the following assumptions:

1. By "query" you mean SQL query.
2. Said query is an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.
3. You're using MySQL.

This [random page on the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html) suggests that a row cannot exceed more than 65,535 bytes. So, if the size of the JSON string plus the size of other columns, plus overhead from all the data exceeds this limit you'll run into issues. Since you mentioned a range of 50,000 - 68,000, I'm inclined to look at this as a problem.

> The internal representation of a MySQL table has a maximum row size
>   limit of 65,535 bytes, even if the storage engine is capable of
>   supporting larger rows. BLOB and TEXT columns only contribute 9 to 12
>   bytes toward the row size limit because their contents are stored
>   separately from the rest of the row.

By the sounds of this documentation, you should convert the JSON column from a `VARCHAR` to a `TEXT` to get around this limit. This relies on yet another assumption that you declared the JSON string column to be a varchar.

Comment: It's not a MYSQL bug - that was my first guess. But the request variables themselves turn to null in the Controller logic - before we make any saves to the mySQL database.

Comment: Sorry I was vague about query - I meant query to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED IT! First, post_max_size in php.ini and max_client_body_size in NGINX are the 2 variables that may matter when it comes to POST payload dropping.

Turns out, however, it was more specific. The issue wasn't the length of payload, it was that I was sending a Javascript Object not a JSON string. PHP has a 1000 default limit on variables for a POST req or it will drop all of them. Apparently this extends to Object Variables as well.

Nuts.